# Reason behind using x.head, x.tail: _* in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to change the order of the columns in a dataframe and found out that the correct way to do it was the following:
 `val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String] = ??? // the new order of columns`

`val result: DataFrame = dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNames.head, reorderedColumnNames.tail: _*)`

And my question is:
Why it can´t be done like the following if the colon ": _*" is supposed to get you all the elements of a collection (Seq, List or Array)?
`val result: DataFrame = dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNames: _*)`

I don't understand why the second way isn't accepted by Spark (and produces an error) because both ways are supposed to be equivalent

Comment: This looks like a scala issue more than a spark one - but admitedly spark helps understanding the context. Why python though ? I've edited the tags, but feel free to revert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The API of `Dataset` requires it to be this way.

First, `Dataframe` is (since 2.0 as I recall, more or less) just a `Dataset[Row]` in terms of implementation, so you have to check the [API doc of Dataset](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html).

Looking at the `select` method, there are two implementations to chose from.

```
def select(col: String, cols: String*): DataFrame
```

This one accepts a single `String`, followed by any number of `String`s.

```
def select(cols: Column*): DataFrame
```

This one accepts any number of `Column` instances.

Your sample code : `val reorderedColumnNames: Array[String]` is an array of string. As such, you can only use the string variant of the method, which requires the use of at least one `String` argument, followed by possibly others.
That is why you can not expand your array directly.

If you were to convert your `Array[String]` to an `Array[Column]`, it would work, that is :

```
val reorderedColumnNamesAsCols: Array[Column] = reorderedColumnNames.map(col(_))
dataFrame.select(reorderedColumnNamesAsCols: _*)
```

Now why not also propose a `select(cols: String*)` variant ? I have no knowledge of if / why this has been proposed but I *guess* that it would not play nicely by the compiler.
We can check :

```
scala> class Test {
 |   def test(strs: String*): Unit = {}
 |   def test(nbrs: Integer*): Unit = {}
 | }
<console>:13: error: double definition:
def test(strs: String*): Unit at line 12 and
def test(nbrs: Integer*): Unit at line 13
have same type after erasure: (strs: Seq)Unit
     def test(nbrs: Integer*): Unit = {}
         ^
```

Compiler not happy.